# return value to fragment from activity android

Tags: android-activity, android-fragments

I have Fragment(F) which calls the activity(A). On press of button(B) in activity(A) the activity must return selected arraylist value back to fragment(F) and finish activity(A)... is this possible?

I know from Activity you can send data with intent as:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "value");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragmentobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragmentobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("key");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

but this works for calling new fragment not working with same fragment.

My question: is it possible for called Activity to return value to caller fragment?

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
    Button attachment;
    String strtext = "check";   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, null);     
        attachment = (Button) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_activity);       
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Key= " + strtext,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        attachment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.class);
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(myIntent,999); 

            }
        });

        return rootView;

    }   

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {        

        if(requestCode == 999){
        strtext = getArguments().getString("key"); 

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Key= " + strtext,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

In Called Activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "value");
HomeFragment fragmentobj = new HomeFragment();
fragmentobj.setArguments(bundle);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragment(F) call the startActivityForResult() method to start the activity A, then override onActivityResult() method in the fragment.

So when the activity A finishes you can get get the result bundle in onActivityResult() method.

**EDIT**

In your fragment onClick() call the activity like this

```
Intent myIintent=new Intent(getActivity(), AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIintent, 999);
```

And in your activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key", "value");
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
```

Now you will get the result in onActivityResult() method of the fragment.

**EDIT2**

In your fragment onActivityResult() method you have to get the data like this...

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    strtext =   extras.getString("key");
```

Comment: i have made as per you told me and have posted code above can you please tell this is what u meant cuz its still not working....

Comment: if getActivity() is removed from startActivityForResult(myIintent, 999); then the app crashes... if not removed works fine but no result

Comment: What exception your getting?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=999, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.isummation.customgallery/.AndroidCustomGalleryActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.isummation.customgallery/com.isummation.customgallery.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: See my edited answer2 and once check your activity code also...have to writing the code in activity which given??

Comment: how to pass arraylist<string> from activity(A) to fragment(B)? is it possible only with Serializable or Parcelable?

Comment: You can use bundle.putParcelableArrayList(key, arrayList) to send array list. The objects in the ArrayList should be Parcellable